# How does the select() function in the select module of Python exactly work?

Tags: python, sockets, select, network-programming

I am working on writing a network-oriented application in Python. I had earlier worked on using blocking sockets, but after a better understanding of the requirement and concepts, I am wanting to write the application using non-blocking sockets and thus an event-driven server.

I understand that the functions in the select module in Python are to be used to conveniently see which socket interests us and so forth. Towards that I was basically trying to flip through a couple of examples of an event-driven server and I had come across this one:

```
"""
An echo server that uses select to handle multiple clients at a time.
Entering any line of input at the terminal will exit the server.
"""

import select
import socket
import sys

host = ''
port = 50000
backlog = 5
size = 1024
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host,port))
server.listen(backlog)
input = [server,sys.stdin]
running = 1
while running:
    inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(input,[],[])

    for s in inputready:

        if s == server:
            # handle the server socket
            client, address = server.accept()
            input.append(client)

        elif s == sys.stdin:
            # handle standard input
            junk = sys.stdin.readline()
            running = 0

        else:
            # handle all other sockets
            data = s.recv(size)
            if data:
                s.send(data)
            else:
                s.close()
                input.remove(s)
server.close()
```

The parts that I didn't seem to understand are the following:

In the code snippet `inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(input,[],[])`, I believe the `select()` function returns three possibly empty lists of waitable objects for input, output and exceptional conditions. So it makes sense that the first argument to the `select()` function is the list containing the server socket and the stdin. However, where I face confusion is in the `else` block of the code.

Since we are for-looping over the list of inputready sockets, it is clear that the `select()` function will choose a client socket that is ready to be read. However, after we read data using `recv()` and find that the socket has actually sent data, we would want to echo it back to the client. My question is how can we write to this socket without adding it to the list passed as second argument to the `select()` function call? Meaning, how can we call `send()` on the new socket directly without 'registering' it with `select()` as a writable socket?

Also, why do we loop only over the sockets ready to be read (inputready in this case)? Isn't it necessary to loop over even the outputready list to see which sockets are ready to be written?
Obviously, I am missing something here.

It would also be really helpful if somebody could explain in a little more detailed fashion the working of `select()` function or point to good documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're being confused by the details of the sample code. Calling send on a socket without waiting for it to be ready to write is fine, but will block if the outgoing buffer is full. They're ignoring this case in your sample code. You might want to look up the `select` man page, since this is a thin wrapper around it. I assume you've found http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably that snippet of code is just a simple example and so it is not exhaustive. You are free to write and read in every socket, also if select does not tell you that they are ready. But, of course, if you do this you cannot be sure that your send() won't block.
So, yes, it would be best practice to rely on select also for writing operations.
There are also many other function which have a similar purpose and in many cases they are better then select (e.g. [epoll](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.epoll)), but they are not available on all platforms.
Information about the select, epoll & other functions may be found in Linux man pages.

However in python there are many nice libraries used to handle many connections, some of these are: [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/) and [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/)

Comment: Thank you @Faust. Would it be an uphill task to code the app without the help of Twisted or the like?

Comment: It depends on your needs. For example a lib like gevent is able to choose the best tool available on the current platform (i.e. epoll on Linux and kqueue on FreeBSD). You can do it your own, but if your project is more than an experiment and you really need best performance, probably, it will be better to rely on widely used and tested tools like gevent or Twisted.
Reaching the level of optimization of those library won't be easy.