# How to implement select() module function in TCP server

Tags: python, sockets, select, ubuntu-16.04, tcpserver

I’m trying to implement the `TCP server` that can handle the client by using select module function but I'm confusing with the tutorial from

1. [How does the select() function in the select module of Python exactly work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471816/how-does-the-select-function-in-the-select-module-of-python-exactly-work)
2. https://pymotw.com/2/select

I want to know. Is my code correct or not? and If not How can I fixed it.

server side

```
import socket,sys,os,select,Queue
HOST = 'localhost'                 
PORT = 3820

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setblocking(0)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

server.listen(5)
inputs = [ server ]

while (1):
    inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(inputs,[],[])
    for s in inputready:
        if s is server:
            conn, addr = server.accept()
            print 'Client connected ..'
            conn.setblocking(0)
            inputs.append(conn)
        else:
            reqCommand = conn.recv(2048)
            if reqCommand:
            print 'Client> %s' %(reqCommand)

    if (reqCommand == 'quit'):
        print 'Client disconected'
        break

    #list file on server
    elif (reqCommand == 'lls'):
        start_path = os.listdir('.') # server directory
        for path,dirs,files in os.walk(start_path):
            for filename in files:
                print os.path.join(filename)

    else:
        string = reqCommand.split(' ', 1)   #in case of 'put' and 'get' method
        reqFile = string[1] 

        if (string[0] == 'put'):
            with open(reqFile, 'wb') as file_to_write:
                while True:
                    data = conn.recv(2048)
                    # print data
                    if not data:
                        break
                    # print data
                    file_to_write.write(data)
                    file_to_write.close()
                    break
            print 'Receive Successful'

        elif (string[0] == 'get'):
            with open(reqFile, 'rb') as file_to_send:
                for data in file_to_send:
                    conn.sendall(data)
            print 'Send Successful'

conn.close()

server.close()
```

Comment: What do *you* think? Is it correct? Have you tried it? Does it work? For example, I "sense" a `NameError` for `reqCommand` when the 1st connection arrives.

Comment: Put each import in a separate line. Remove the parenthesis from the `if`s. Use `while True:`.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I try to test by using put command but It stuck in 'quit' condition that I've not done it yet       "NameError: name 'reqCommand' is not defined'
. I passed through the upper code.  So, if I go the right way. I just want to know. what should I do next with the 'put' and 'get' the command. @CristiFati

Answer (score 1):

If you use `select` you should not set non-blocking mode, because each request does not block. You don't use output in select; you must check, if output is ready if you like to send something.

You don't use a protocol. `recv` can receive up to 1024 bytes, but you have also to handle the case, that each `recv` reads only one byte. So you have to know (by the protocol) when `reqCommand` is complete.

With `select` you must not use `while`-loops to receive more data. You have to read blocks in the main loop, and store them, until the transmission is complete.

With `select` you must not use `for`-loops and `sendall` to send data. You have to ask the socket via `select` if it is ready to output data and use `send` and it`s return value to know how many bytes already sent.

You don't handle closed connections.